# Указатель на метод класса внутри класса

Tags: c++, классы, функции, указатели

Мне понадобилась масса таймеров на чистом с++. Для решения задачи я пытаюсь использовать список, элементы которого содержат указатели на функции которые выполнятся, когда счётчик времени в элементе подойдёт к концу. Ну и раз в рабочий цикл пробегаюсь по списку и исполняю всё.
Вся эта конструкция лежит внутри родителя(CProtoLayer) класса-слоя в котором крутятся свои задачи. Как указатель я использую конструкцию void(*func)(void), но когда я пытаюсь туда вставить метод из класса-наследника(CPlLayer) компилятор ругается на несовместимость void(CPlLayer::*)(void) и void(*)(void).
Собственно как мне описать эту систему в классе родителе, чтобы потом нормально с ней работать?

Класс родитель -

```
class CProtoLayer
{
public:
CProtoLayer(void);
~CProtoLayer(void);
nsap my_sap;
void start_task(int param);
CMsgQueue *general_messages;
CMS_conf *configuration;

class CTimeUnit
{
public:
    CTimeUnit();
    CTimeUnit(void (*callback)(void), CProtoLayer* o);
    ~CTimeUnit();

    void SetTimer(uint32_t t);
    void Start();
    void Stop();

    uint32_t time_stump;
    uint32_t time_left;
    bool running;
    void (*callback)(void);
    CTimeUnit *next;
    CProtoLayer *owner;
};  

CTimeUnit *TimeAddUnit(void (*callback)(void));
void TimeDeleteUnit(CTimeUnit* tu);
CTimeUnit *time_head;
CTimeUnit *time_work_head;

uint32_t GetCurrentTime();
uint32_t time_old;

void TimerIrqHandler();

protected:
Nprimitive* m_rxsig;
virtual void task (void) = 0;
void send_ev(Nprimitive *prim)
{
    CMsg* tmp_msg = new CMsg();
    tmp_msg->SetPrimitive(prim);
    general_messages->PushMsg(tmp_msg);
}

};
```

класс наследник -

```
class CPlLayer :public CProtoLayer
{
public:
CPlLayer(void);
~CPlLayer(void);
void task(void);
PL_SAP_ns::TEXT_ind* text_msg;

DLL_SAP_ns::LC_voice_req* lcvoice_req;
DLL_SAP_ns::VOICE_data *voice_data;

CRxSimulator *simulator;
void simbegin();
};
```

конструктор наследника -

```
CPlLayer::CPlLayer(void)
{
my_sap = PL_SAP;
text_msg = new PL_SAP_ns::TEXT_ind();
text_msg->m_sap = UI_SAP;
text_msg->m_type = Nprimitive::Nindication;
text_msg->m_id = TEXT;
text_msg->str = "Hello UI from PL";

lcvoice_req = new DLL_SAP_ns::LC_voice_req();
lcvoice_req->m_sap = DLL_SAP;
lcvoice_req->m_type = Nprimitive::Nrequest;
lcvoice_req->m_id = LC_VOICE;
lcvoice_req->FID = 0;
lcvoice_req->FLCO = 0;
lcvoice_req->service = 0;
lcvoice_req->src_addr = 0;
lcvoice_req->dst_addr = 0;
lcvoice_req->BurstSetSlot(0, DT_LC_HEAD);

voice_data = new DLL_SAP_ns::VOICE_data();
voice_data->BurstSetEMB(0, 0, 0);
voice_data->m_sap = DLL_SAP;
voice_data->m_type = Nprimitive::Nrequest;
voice_data->m_id = DATA_VOICE;
voice_data->burst->data_block->data = (uint8_t*)("Hello.Good news, everyone.\n");

simulator = new CRxSimulator();
TimeAddUnit(simbegin); //ошибка здесь
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код и текст ошибки пожалуйста к вопросу, это поможет дать ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вам следует воспользоваться `std::bind`.

Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что  `void(CPlLayer::*)(void)` должен получать параметр - если это нестатическая функция-член - а именно, объект, для которого она вызывается. Грубо говоря, при наличии

```
class Test
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "Test::f\n"; }
};
```

вы не можете вызвать `Test::f()`, и должны передать какой-то объект -

```
Test t;
t.f();
```

Ну, а чтоб все это унифицировать и позволить использовать лямбды и функциональные объекты - я бы предложил `std::function`. Что-то [вроде](https://ideone.com/z2mvSw)

```
class Test
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "Test::f\n"; }
};

void g() { cout << "g\n"; }


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t;
    std::function<void(void)> f[] =
        {g,std::bind(&Test::f,t), [](){cout << "lambda\n";}};
    for(auto s: f) s();
}
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

**Update**

К вашему дополненному вопросу - вот тут

```
void (*callback)(void);
```

я бы использовал

```
std::function<void(void)> callback;
```

Тогда в качестве этого `callback` вы можете использовать все, что угодно...

Comment: Я бы принял ответ: по моему так...

Comment: Да, всё так, это просто я медленный.